# Почему при переносе на реальное устройство - Sorry, sensor not available for this device

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Здравствуйте.

В приложение поместил возможность считывания значения датчика температуры окружающей среды

```
temperaturelabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTemp);
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
    mTemperature= mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE); 
}
if (mTemperature == null) {
    temperaturelabel.setText(NOT_SUPPORTED_MESSAGE);
}
```

при запуске в эмуляторе

```
Name: Nexus_6_API_27 CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86) Path: C:\Users\drno\.android\avd\Nexus_6_API_27.avd Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 27) Skin: nexus_6 SD Card: 100M hw.dPad: no runtime.network.speed: full hw.accelerometer: yes hw.device.name: Nexus 6 vm.heapSize: 256 skin.dynamic: yes hw.device.manufacturer: Google hw.gps: yes hw.initialOrientation: Portrait image.androidVersion.api: 27 hw.audioInput: yes image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\ tag.id: google_apis showDeviceFrame: yes hw.camera.back: emulated hw.mainKeys: no AvdId: Nexus_6_API_27 hw.camera.front: emulated hw.lcd.density: 560 avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 6 API 27 hw.gpu.mode: auto hw.device.hash2: MD5:9b564b60b1aebee32c73ded9daa1e620 hw.ramSize: 1536 hw.trackBall: no hw.battery: yes hw.cpu.ncore: 4 hw.sdCard: yes tag.display: Google APIs runtime.network.latency: none hw.keyboard: yes hw.sensors.proximity: yes disk.dataPartition.size: 800M hw.sensors.orientation: yes avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8 hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

OK

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

собрал APK залил в Samsung Galaxy Note 4
приложение вернуло ошибку о недоступности сенсора температуры - S**orry, sensor not available for this device**

Прошу помочь разобраться в причине.

P.s. [ссылка на проект](https://github.com/drno-reg/android_app_1.git)

Comment: А вы уверены, что в данном аппарате есть датчик температуры?

Comment: Вы правы в speco по Samsung Galaxy Note 4 нет датчика температуры (((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В устройстве Samsung Galaxy Note 4 нет датчика температуры,
его даже нет во флагмане 2017 года Samsung Galaxy S8+.